# Notice: Undefined index: adObjID in /home/xxxxxxx on line 28

Tags: php, arrays, web, undefined-index

in my script there is an error 
Notice: Undefined index: adObjID in /home/reffsite/xxxx.com/sell-edit-item.php on line 28

I don't know what is the problem for real since im not good in coding

```
/* Variables */
$adObjID = $_GET['adObjID'];
$adObj   = new ParseObject('Ads', $adObjID);
$adObj->fetch();
```

this is the line 28

anyone can help me solve this please

Answer (score 0):

You must be Missing the `GET` in browser when visiting the link.

```
http://someurl.com?adObjID=something
```

Your URL Must have `adObjID` as a `GET` variable!

Comment: https://imgur.com/rM1an4Y
look at the image bro 
and i can't even get add images and nothing 
im not good at coding

Comment: @WidchyJoachim Please Try like this [link](http://dealnou.com/sell-edit-item.php?adObjID=) http://dealnou.com/sell-edit-item.php?adObjID=